# How to automatically scrolling collectionviewcell to nearest cell(previous or next) when selecting a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm currently working on a swift application. In one view controller I have a `collectionView` with horizontal scrolling. The `collectionView` is look like horizontal tabs with more tabs. So some `collectionViewCell's` are not visible at initial time.

What I need is I want to auto-scroll the collectionView to next cell(if collectionView has an invisible cell in the right) or to the previous cell(if it has an invisible cell in the left) when I select a `collectionViewCell`. I was using a cocoa pod(`SwipeMenuViewController`), but it is making some issue with the presentation. Please help me to implement the same with collectionView.

Please see the image for more clarity.

[image]

This is my code,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tabArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "tabCell", for: indexPath) as! tabCollectionViewCell
    cell.tabLabel.text = self.tabArray[indexPath.row]
    if selectedTabArray.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.bottomView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.bottomView.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedTabArray.removeAll()
    selectedTabArray.append(indexPath)
    self.tabCollectionView.reloadData()
    tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just scroll to that `indexPath` on `didSelectItemAt` Method

```
var selectedIndex = 0

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "tabCell", for: indexPath) as! tabCollectionViewCell
    cell.tabLabel.text = self.tabArray[indexPath.item]
    if self.selectedIndex == indexpath.item {
        cell.bottomView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.bottomView.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedIndex = indexpath.item
    self.tabCollectionView.reloadData()
    tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
```

Hope this Help!

Comment: for this case  it would be `.centeredHorizontally` not  `.centeredVertically`

Comment: But for me, when I select the last cell, the collectionView autoscroll to first cell.

Comment: @Hilaj can you pls post you code? so that we can see what goes wrong.

Comment: I added my code in the question. Why I'm reloading means, I need to highlight the selected tab.

Comment: @Hilaj why are you reload collectionView?

Comment: @Hilaj if you must have to reload collectionView than first reload and than scroll to that cell

Comment: I did that too. But that time, it is not autoscrolling to the nearest cell.

Comment: Can I able to avoid reloadData(), for highlight the selected cell. Is there any other way.

Comment: @Hilaj can you pls post your cellForItemAt method, bcoz it is working for me

Comment: i have update the answer, pls try and let me know, is it working or not?

Comment: Still not working. I think the reloading and scrollToItem is happening in the same thread. May be bcoz of that, the autoscrolling in not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206432/discussion-between-kaushik-orangeapp-and-hilaj).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `didSelectRowAt` method to get the `indexPath` of the selected cell. then check if the cell is not the last cell. If it is not, scroll to right, else scroll to left.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true) 
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

}
```

**UPDATE1:**

I didn't see the image when answering the question as it was not added yet. I have update my answer.

**UPDATE2:**

In your viewDidLoad,

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false // in your view didLoad
```

then use property observers to change the selected index.

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) {
    didSet {
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [selectedIndexPath])
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tabArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "tabCell", for: indexPath) as! tabCollectionViewCell
    cell.tabLabel.text = self.tabArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.bottomView.isHidden = (indexPath == selectedIndexPath) ? false : true
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! tabCollectionViewCell
    cell.bottomView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, its working fine. But when I select the last cell, it auto scrolls to first. Actually in the didSelect method I'm reloading the collectionView.

Comment: @Hilaj updated the answer. dont use reloadData(), reload that particular row only.

Comment: Not bcoz of reloading the all cells, unselected cells also shows in highlight

Comment: Here it is not clearing selection from the previously selected cells, and adding selection to the new selected cells.

Comment: yes, but on selection, the collectionView is struggling to scroll and present the data

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. But still the selection is there for previous cell. To clear the selection, I need to click again. Here what I need is same as the above image. On click of new cell, I need to add a selectionView on the new cell and need to clear selectionView from the previous.

Comment: whatever you need to remove, you can do it in **didDeselectItemAt** method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedIndex = 0

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "tabCell", for: indexPath) as! tabCollectionViewCell
    cell.tabLabel.text = self.tabArray[indexPath.item]
    if self.selectedIndex == indexpath.item {
        cell.bottomView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.bottomView.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
    }
```

Replace `collectionView didSelectItemAt` with following method to solve selection issue and reload collectionview,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.selectedIndex = indexpath.item
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
                tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }) { (_) in
                self.tabCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
}
```